# how to switch between the default and hidden token channels in an ANTLR grammar

Tags: switch-statement, antlr, token, channel

I have a parser rule like this

```
if_stmt : IF_T condition THEN_T
          {
           /* Here I would like to change the channel and iterate through the tokens
              from hidden channel*/
           code.....
           /* Here I would like to change it to default token channel again */
          }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Once the rule is matched, I would like to check whether "THEN_T" is followed by any code in the same line or the line ends with "THEN_T".

Comment: If line breaks matter in your language, then why don't you use an EOL (end-of-line) token?